# "find -atime -1d" выдает "find: missing argument to `-atime'"

Tags: debian

Сабж. На freebsd такая малина

> find -atime -1d

работает на ура, на дебиане (5) выдает мне

> find: missing argument to `-atime'

вопрос еще актуален..

Comment: @bsdmacs продолжим тут )короче, все вами описанные функции выдают одно и тоже: абсолютно все файлы (рекрусивно) в директории, толи у меня что-то с головой, толи Вы неправильно толкуете, толи (что очень уж маловероятно) баг дебиана )

Comment: @Ozim, попробуйте на другом каталоге. Я описываю здесь лишь то, что написано в man pages.

Comment: Ну конечно я пробовал на разных..

Comment: вопрос решен. Проблема была в том, что все мне показывали -n, в то время когда - там не нужно, синтаксис такой: >find ctime 3

Answer (score 2):

[[[[@Ozim](/users/75/ozim)](/users/75/ozim)](/users/75/ozim)](/users/75/ozim), [[@byte](/users/8/byte)](/users/8/byte) написал все правильно, только не аргументировал свой ответ. На самом деле это одно из отличий реализации утилиты GNU find, которая используется в Debian. И утилиты find, которая соответствует стандартам POSIX и используется во FreeBSD и других BSD тоже.

Во FreeBSD синтаксис

```
find -atime -1d30h
```

В Debian то же самое будет выглядеть так

```
find -amin -90
```

[[[[@Ozim](/users/75/ozim)](/users/75/ozim)](/users/75/ozim)](/users/75/ozim), в приведенном Вами примере необходимо использовать такой синтаксис

```
find -atime -n
```

В Вашем примере n принимает значение 1 и ,в свою очередь умножается на 24 часа, т.о получаются одни сутки.

**P.S.** Об этой особенности написано в страницах руководства (`man find`).

**P.P.S.** Вот выдержка из man pages Ubuntu:

> **-atime n** 
> File was last accessed n*24 hours ago.  When find figures outhow many 24-hour periods ago the filewas last accessed, any fractional partis ignored, so to match -atime +1, afile has to have been accessed atleast two days ago.
>
> **-amin n** 
> File was last accessed n minutes ago.

**P.P.P.S.** Уточняю:

*-atime* - показать файлы, к которым обращались за указанный промежуток времени.

*-ctime* - файлы, которые были созданы за указанный промежуток времени.

*-mtime* - файлы, которые изменялись за указанный промежуток времени.

Comment: тогда почему команда>find -atime -1выдает **все** файлы, а не за последний час?

Comment: Потому, что когда используется -atime, то ее аргумент (в данном случае 1) умножается на 24 часа и она выдает файлы не за последний час, а за последние 24 часа. Чтобы получить за последний час нужно -amin -60.

Comment: она все равно выдает те же файлы, тупо все файлы, какие есть в директории, хоть 1 хоть 60

Comment: @Ozim, Вы задаете -atime или -amin? Что за папка? У меня все работает абсолютно также хорошо, как и на FreeBSD.

Comment: atime, папка с файлами сайта, менялись / изменялись файлы черт знает когда, не вчера и даже не неделю назад.

Comment: Проверьте все еще раз. У меня утилита find работает нормально. Единственный вариант при котором она может выдать все файлы - они изменялись.

Comment: уверяю вас, они не менялись.

Comment: Прошу прощения - у меня к концу рабочего дня "крыша поехала". -atime - показать файлы к которым обращались. -ctime - показать файлы, которые создавались. -mtime - показать файлы, которые изменялись.

Answer (score 1):

Видимо, для Debian после цифры 1 не должно быть буквы d. Такой вызов работает правильно

```
find . -atime -1
```

Ищет все файлы в дереве, к которым не обращались в течение менее, чем 1 день.

Comment: Ищет вообще все, просто тупо все.p.s. 1 чего? с чего инфа что это день?.. как тогда прописать час?..вобщем - неверно.